# Accept network traffic in one Instance from other Instances in a managed instance group in Google Cloud

Tags: firewall, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I am stuck with this. I have a Managed Instance Group (MIG) hosting a single application (autoscaled) and I have another single instance which hosts the Database. I am trying to set a firewall rule that allows Database connections only from the MIG.

First, I created an ingress Firewall Rule that allows Database Traffic to the Database Instance on port `5432` with a specified Target Tag of `allow-db-connections`. I placed the tag into the Instance settings and it is able to receive database connections from that port. I am now trying to figure out what to put in the Source Filter so that it only accepts connections from instances in the MIG.

I would appreciate any ideas. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**STEP 1:**

VPC networks have a default rule **default-allow-internal**. This allows all traffic within a VPC. Click on that rule, scroll to the bottom and see which instances it applies to. That rule has a target of **All instances in the network**. Either disable or modify the rule.

**STEP 2:**

1. Assign a tag to the VM instance template. For example **DBClient**.
2. Assign a tag to the database server. For example **DBServer**.
3. Create a firewall rule with the name **allow-db-connections**.
4. Specify the **Targets** to be **Specified target tags**.
5. Specify the **target tags** with the value **DBServer**.
6. Specify the **Source filter** to be **Source tags**.
7. Specify the **Source tags** with the value **DBClient**.
8. Specify the other fields as you require.

This VPC rule will only allow traffic from the VM instances tagged **DBClient** to the VM instance tagged **DBServer**.

Comment: Thanks a bunch @john. That worked like a charm.

Comment: @realnsleo - happy to help.